# Where clause using db prefix onto two tables

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, activerecord

I need to write a query of the form of join in where clause :

```
$this->db->where('user.client_id','client.id'); //essentially getting those rows of user and client table where the client_id matches
$this->db->where('user.id',$id);
```

Also, I have used a `db_prefix` in the database.php. The problem with this is that the prefix gets added to the 'user' table but not 'client' table for the first 'where' statement.

I have reverted to using 'join' statements, but is it possible to use the 'where' statement and also get the prefix to the second argument?

Comment: Does "$this->db->set_dbprefix('newprefix');" suit your needs? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Comment: it says for use in a native sql query.. i am using active records.

Comment: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/fe9309d22c1b088f5363954d6dac013c8c955894/system/database/DB_query_builder.php then check out method _wh and see if you can somehow solve it using the $this->db->where, or you need to refactor. (sorry, no time now to dig deeper)